# Get the closest match in a string

Tags: javascript

I have a json file with some domains which I try to match in a foreach object function.

JSON-File:

```
  "calendar-google": {
    "domainMatch": "calendar.google",
    "icon": "assets/icons/google-calendar.png"
  },
  "inbox-google": {
    "domainMatch": "inbox.google",
    "icon": "assets/icons/google-gmail.png"
  },
  "github": {
    "domainMatch": "github",
    "icon": "assets/icons/github.png"
  },
  "google": {
    "domainMatch": "google",
    "icon": "assets/icons/google-google.png"
  },
  "trello": {
    "domainMatch": "trello",
    "icon": "assets/icons/trello.png"
  },
  "tweetdeck": {
    "domainMatch": "tweetdeck.twitter",
    "icon": "assets/icons/twitter.png"
  },
  "twitter": {
    "domainMatch": "twitter",
    "icon": "assets/icons/twitter.png"
  },
  "youtube": {
    "domainMatch": "youtube",
    "icon": "assets/icons/youtube.png"
  }
```

Now I want to check if my url in my local storage does match with one of these "domainMatch" properties.

JavaScript:

```
$.getJSON("domainList.json", function  (data) {
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data).forEach(function(val, idx, array) {

            var domainMatch = data[val].domainMatch

            if(localStorage.getItem("favouriteSite")) {
                var sites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("favouriteSite"));

                // Lets think firstlink is "calender.google.com"

                var firstLink = sites.site1.link;

                if(firstLink.includes(domainMatch)){
                    // 2 Results but I want only that
                    // result which is near!!     
                }

            }
        });
```

You see in the comment, that I not want the match "google" and "calender.google". I want only the nearest match from both (calender.google in this case).

How can I get the nearest match of a string?

When I did not write something detailed enough, then please write it but I think you should understand what I mean.

Greetings
Julian

Comment: `.includes()` function returns a boolean value - `true` or `false`. So how can it be that you get two results?

Comment: With strings, you can check for an exact match or if a given string is within another string. There is no built-in mechanism for a "closest match". You will need to write your own algorithm for that.

Comment: @Kinduser Sorry for the misunderstanding. When I log every match, then "true" appear two times.

Comment: Drop `console.log('res')` inside the `if` statement. Will it log twice?

Comment: @Kinduser Yes, cause "google" and "calender.google" is included.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `forEach`, use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the first match or `null` if nothing is matched like this:

```
$.getJSON("domainList.json", function(data) {
  var sites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("favouriteSite")); // this should be out here (so you won't fetch it evertime)
  var firstLink = sites.site1.link;

  var val = Object.keys(data).find(function(key) { // find will stop at the first found item (Object.keys) is better since it's just a plain object)
    var domainMatch = data[key].domainMatch;

    return firstLink.includes(domainMatch);
  });
  console.log(val); // val will be the first matched key ('github', 'google', ...) or null if nothing is matched


  /***************** EDIT: **********************/
  if(val) {                // if we found something
      var obj = data[val]; // get the object (because val is the key)
      var icon = obj.icon; // now obj is an object from the array data (you can access its icon property like this)
  }
});
```

Comment: Now, I want to access the icon property of the object which will be returned. How can I do that?

Comment: Ok, thanks, it works! But I have a little question anyway. When I set the _calender-google_ object at the bottom of the json file, it will return the _google_ object, not the calender one. So the _calender-google_ object must set above the _google_ object property. Is there a solution to "fix" that too?

Comment: @julianYaman you said the nearest so if calendar.goole is at the bottom then it's not the nearest!

Comment: Ok, maybe it was the false term to describe what I want. I want to get the closest correct result I can get. (When I have "_**calender.google**.com_" and it matches with "_google_" and "_calender.google_", I want only "_calender.google_" cause it matches more than "_google_")

Comment: @julianYaman do you have the same string in localstorage as in the response? I mean do you have `calendar-google` both in localstorage and response.

Comment: No, I don´t set this value in the localStorage. But it must be possible to get the best match from two different values...

Answer (score 0):

Use [**Array.prototype.some()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function to return the result immediately on the first match:

```
$.getJSON("domainList.json", function  (data) {
    var matched = Object.keys(data).some(function(k) {
        var domainMatch = data[k].domainMatch;

        if (localStorage.getItem("favouriteSite")) {
            var sites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("favouriteSite"));

            // Lets think firstlink is "calender.google.com"
            var firstLink = sites.site1.link;

            return firstLink.includes(domainMatch);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: some returns true or false, it doesn't return value returned by the function. I think you're looking for `reduce`.

Comment: the main idea I could recognize was the OP's *I want to check if my url in my local storage does match with one of these "domainMatch"*